# Looking for sample global.asax.cs files for routing information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, global-asax

No matter what you read about [ASP.NET routing](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/06/chapter-2-understanding-routing.aspx) or REST I think the best way to learn more about them is to read other people's routing files. In a video with [Jeff](http://codinghorror.com) once you could catch a glimpse of the [stackoverflow routing file if you paused the video in the right place](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/09/15/stackoverflow-at-pdc.aspx). I actually learnt quite a lot just looking at how it was organized.

To that end - does anybody want to post their routing data (in full or in part) from global.asax.cs for others to learn from? I'll post mine when its more organized - kind of messy now.

Tip: Not that you should have any security holes - but you might want to check that theres nothing 'secret' in your file before you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials) for mvc sample apps.

Answer (score 2):

Quite surprised to see the [NerdDinner](http://www.codeplex.com/nerddinner) routing file only has one custom route. Proof that if you follow convention that you can use the routing handler 'out of the box'.

```
namespace NerdDinner {

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {

        public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "UpcomingDinners", 
                "Dinners/Page/{page}", 
                new { controller = "Dinners", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        void Application_Start() {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a live application.

http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg/SourceControl/changeset/view/18277#347257

Application hosted at www.dotnetshoutout.com